# Can't install Franz

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, 32-bit, franz

Linux noob here.
My PC runs Lubuntu 18.04.0 LTS(32-bit).
Yesterday, I was trying to install franz-5.5.0(the all-in-one messaging app).
I couldn't find it in Ubuntu repository(Correct me if I'm wrong: You gotta type `apt-cache search Franz*` right?) nor in the software center. I went to their website and downloaded the .deb file but that didn't install because it was 64 bit architecture. I downloaded the other .AddImage file (I didn't know what it was at that time). Again correct me if I'm wrong: It is a file that can be executed independent of the linux distro. I gave permissions to the file to be executed by anyone after downloading. But when I double-clicked it, NOTHING HAPPENED. I mean nothing. Could anyone help me out? Sorry if I couldn't provide the required info to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no 32-bit binary available. So you can't install it on a 32-bit system.

If your CPU supports 64-bit architecture, consider installing a 64-bit Lubuntu.